# Specified cast is not valid and Index was outside of the bounds array

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I wanna show different data from ms access to different combo boxes. But I get "specified cast is not valid error". When I try ".GetString(1)" on the second getstring I get"Index was outside of the bounds array"

```
    connection.Open()

    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("select LRN from Table1", connection)
    Dim reader As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader

    While reader.Read
        GunaComboBox1.Items.Add(reader.GetString(0))

    End While

    Dim connection1 As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=BookDB.mdb")
    connection1.Open()
    Dim cmd1 As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("select [Book ID] from Books1", connection1)

    Dim reader1 As OleDbDataReader = cmd1.ExecuteReader
    While reader1.Read
        GunaComboBox2.Items.Add(reader1.GetString(0))


    End While
   
End Sub
```

Comment: This will probably sound a bit rude, but honestly you’ve asked nearly the same question at least 3 or 4 times in the last week with only some slight differences.  I would suggest you might consider actually taking some time to understand the solutions and suggestions you’ve been given so you know how to apply the knowledge you’ve been given to different context.

Answer (score 2):

You can only call `GetString` if the data you're getting actually is a `String`. If the data is any other type, it will fail. You need to call the appropriate method for the data type, e.g. `GetInt32` if the data is type Integer. You can't call `GetString` and it will convert other data types for you.

Of course `GetString(1)` fails. Both your queries get only one column so how could you possibly get from the second column of your data reader?